# Получение id элемента, который был добавлен после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Есть такой код

```
<p id='666'></p>
<p id='342'></p>
```

После загрузки страницы к нему, по мере необходимости, добавляется еще:

```
<p id='3123'></p>
```

Пробовал таким вариантом:

```
$('p:last').attr("id");
```

но он работает только с теми элементами, которые уже были в DOM

Как отслеживать id последнего элемента вне зависимости от того, был он в DOM изначально или же его добавили после загрузки страницы?

Comment: почему не посмотреть id _перед_ добавлением?

Comment: а в какой момент вы вызываете селектор? почему вы уверены, что элемент уже есть на странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим последовательность. У вас все происходит примерно следующим образом:

1. Загружается DOM и тот контент что в нем есть.
2. Выполняется ваш скрипт, который пробует получить последний элемент P и прочитать его ID.
3. Через какое-то время в будущем, скажем через час(!) выполняется некий, например AJAX запрос и вставляет еще один P в DOM.

Видите, ваш скрипт из пункта 2 уже давно отработал, и он никак не узнает что вы там что-то еще хотите добавить через час.

Но мы помним, что JS может выполнятся асинхронно. Т.е. мы можем заложить в него возможность ожидания некоего события в будущем и реакцию на это.

Самый простой вариант - функция-коллбэк.
Если ваш новый тег P вставляется после AJAX-запроса на сервер, то вы можете подключить коллбэк success и выполнить там свой поиск. Примерно так:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (data) {
        // здесь какой-то код, который вставляет новый тег P на страницу

        // а вот в этой точке вы уже точно знаете что
        // новый тег вставлен и можете вызвать свою функцию
        readLastTag();
    }
    ...
});

function readLastTag () {
    var last_id = $('p:last').attr("id");
    console.log(last_id);
}
```

Точно такие же функции коллбэки можно добавить к другим возможным событиям, например каким-то действиям пользователя (вроде клика мышкой и т.п.)

Comment: самый простой вариант - использовать live collection, которую вернет `getElementsByTagName`